# Detect TOR users with IPv6 exit addresses

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, exit-relays

I need to redirect visitors to .onion site if they come using Tor Browser. It's okay if they have IPv4 IPs (e.g. `51.15.86.162` belongs to tor exit nodes list). But how to do that in case of IPv6 addresses, for example `2a0b:f4c0:16c:13::1` ?
Is there a similar IPv6 exit list or any programmatic method to tell the address is used by exit node?

Comment: You can try the list at https://www.dan.me.uk/torlist/?exit which contains IPv6 addresses, but I haven't looked into specifically how it's generated. You may also be interested in looking into https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/21952.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list of IPv6 addresses of tor exit nodes here (the IPv6 column): https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#search/flag:exit%20

Also, there is no programmatic way to tell a regular ip from a tor exit node ip (except for maybe doing a reverse dns lookup on the ip and checking if the domain has the word "tor" in it)

Answer (score 0):

where I work we have an API that does that, it's in the IDS/IPS services
send a mail to info@asp-waf.com and I will get you access